# How to build a ci / cd pipeline with hybris commerce?

Tags: continuous-integration, sap-commerce-cloud, continuous-delivery, commerce

I am developing a pipeline for hybris.

I have doubts in the execution of the tests.

I'm following this tutorial:
https://clutcher.github.io/post/hybris/improve_hybris_test_run/

However, I have several extensions in customizing hybris.

Do I have to configure the buildcallbacks.xml file for each extension?

Is there any way to run the **ant ci** for all extensions?

Answer (score 0):

For a first version I would use the following ant tasks:

- integrationtests
- performancetests
- manualtests
- bugprooftests
- localizationtest
- typecodetest
- alltests
- allwebtests

Make sure to mark your tests with the `@IntegrationTest` or `@UnitTest` annotation so that the ant task will find them.

You can filter the tests by:

- extensions using the parameter `-Dtestclasses.extensions=myextension`
- packages using the parameter `-Dtestclasses.packages=my.package`
- excluded packages using the parameter `-Dtestclasses.packages.excluded`

For more information consider:
https://help.sap.com/viewer/d0224eca81e249cb821f2cdf45a82ace/2005/en-US/f7f454a4f5254944a366db9bdf129be6.html

Comment: I'm using version 6.7

Comment: ant unittests -Dtestclasses.extensions=extension01,extension02...

Comment: I used it this way. However, some extensions were not found.

Comment: When I run the ant command the answer is as follows: Target "extensionX" does not exist in the project "platform".

Comment: Then maybe you should check your setup. E.g. config/localextensions.xml